# Unable print existing PDF file in Windows 8 using C# code

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, printing

I want to print PDF documents from my winforms application as soon as user clicks the print button in Windows 8. Below is the code I am using:

```
protected void PrintPDF_WithAdobe()
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/p /h E:\Sample.pdf";
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (!proc.HasExited)
        {
            proc.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    if (!proc.HasExited)
    {
        proc.CloseMainWindow();
    }
    proc.Close();
}
```

But it gives error that OS does not supports Arguments passed. The same code is working well in Windows 7. Is there anything in particular I have to do to get it to work in Windows 8?

Comment: What happens if you run the command from the command line (cmd)?

Comment: Two things happening 1. Failed to initialise PNR and 2. Document being printed, but no print coming

Comment: For me - using  Windows 8 - executing the `AcroRd32.exe /p /h` from the command line prints successfully on the default printer. So maybe the problem is with not correctly configured default printer.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work from the command line it will probably also not work from c# code.

You need to figure out how to print a pdf from the command line in windows 8, and use that to replace the command + arguments in your c# code.